# sorting a vector by a parameter

Tags: c++, stl

hello guys i want to do the following thing.
lets say we have a vector of [1 9 6 8 9 10] and i want to sort first time by a criteria, second time by other criteria.(for example if a bool variable is True, sort the vector using first criteria, if it is false, sort the vector using second criteria.
For example, lets sort the vector by first criteria:ascending order
                                     second criteria:descending order.
the output will be [1 10 6 8 9 9].
it's easy to sort the vector with first criteria, then second criteria, but is posibile to do it using stl libraries? :)

Comment: `std::sort` with custom functor?

Comment: Besides [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), I also recommend you read about [*lambda expressions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: please use a search engine before you ask ("vector sort" would give you at least a start and if you run into problems of how to use a custom comparator you could still ask here)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant overload to `std::sort` is ternary:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

So you need to call it via something like

```
std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), factor? first : second);
```

(Provided `first` and `second` are of matching types so third argument compiles.

If they are not, you can wrap them in `std::function`s or something.)

Comment: Technically: comparator doesn't _need_ to be a function. One can implement a class, which has the comparison mechanism contained inside (and chosen based on the values of some internal flags).

Comment: Sure, I never said it needs to be a function. All it needs is to provide `operator()`, and `std::function` is the simplest monomorphic wrapper found in the STL for such cases.

Comment: Sure, it's simplest. But the reason I left such comment is: if you used instance of a `class` as a functor, you could avoid doing `factor? first : second` at every `std::sort` invocation, and, instead, you could just set necessary flags, and leave everything else to the internal implementation of the functor.

Comment: Hmm, "comparison mechanism contained inside (and chosen based on the values of some internal flags)" implies a branch _per each element_ in the best case, doesn't it? Too big a price for saving a single branching _per each sorting_. :-|